# Do MoGenerator templates exits for testing with protocol interfaces?

Tags: unit-testing, templates, core-data, mogenerator

Do MoGenerator templates exits for testing with protocol interfaces ?

( like in http://iamleeg.blogspot.com/2009/09/unit-testing-core-data-driven-apps.html )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so directly, but v1.23's PONSO gets you close(r).

Comment: [The PONSO templates](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator/tree/master/contributed%20templates/Nikita%20Zhuk/ponso)